# What does "areas" refer to?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice

> Then the lumps of clay are placed on a metal grid in order to break up the big chunks of clay into much smaller **areas**, which fall through the metal grid onto a roller, whose motion further segregates the bits of clay.

- What does ***areas*** here refer to?
  What does this word denote here since its basic meaning doesn't seem to fit the context given.
- What other word could have been used in its place?

Comment: Area refers to  (pieces of smaller) size into which big chunks of clay are broken into. Smaller pieces that can fall through the grid.

Comment: Please provide the source of the quotation. Found it. OK it comes from an IELTS [writing task 1 paper](http://www.ielts-writing.info/index.php/academic/ielts-writing-task-1-2/). What you have here is a sample, a piece of writing handed in by a non native speaker who was taking the IELTS exam. The sample is supposed to act only as a guideline. It is not saying this is the perfect way to describe a process.

Comment: The composition is shown to help candidates affront the writing task, unless you know what an examiner is looking for, you won't get the best possible mark. The chances of that same question being asked is nil, so don't fixate over it.

Answer (score 6):

The text (and by implication, [the source website](http://www.ielts-writing.info/index.php/academic/ielts-writing-task-1-2/)) is poor quality.

Someone asked exactly this same question on [wordreference.com](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/what-does-area-here-in-this-sentence-refer-to.3235678/), where "Senior Member" *Copyright* responded...

> *I would say that "lumps" become "pieces" when they are broken up. Not "areas." I wouldn't memorize this for use with the general public.*

(I assume by ***this*** he means the *specific example sentence*, but I would avoid the *entire website*.)

I can't really add much to that apart from to say that I don't think *any* native speaker would use ***areas*** there, since ***lumps*** and ***chunks*** are three-dimensional, but ***areas*** are by definition two-dimensional.

---

The most "natural" word to use in this context is probably ***pieces***. Of the four "synonyms" ***lumps, chunks, bits, pieces***, the first two often imply "large", and the second two often imply "small".

Comment: I wouldn't say the writing sample in the website is of poor quality, it was written (presumably) by a candidate, a non native speaker. I would like to see how many English native speakers would be able to produce a similar piece of written work in their second or third language. BTW +1

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: Look again! The website says this is a ***model*** answer - it's not just an "example". Obviously there shouldn't be any mistakes at all in a "model" answer.

Comment: The mark given is a 9, the writer is (presumably) a candidate. Look again at the description, it's pretty advanced stuff, but for someone like yourself it is flawed. It's good that you pointed out that a native speaker wouldn't use "areas" because it's true, these samples are never supposed to be perfect. The real question is where did the sample originate from? It could be Cambridge who provided the source, but I don't know.

Comment: See the teacher's evaluation: ***Only rare minor
‘slips’ can be found*** *and these do not detract from the high rating*

Comment: ***Area noun (Measure)*** 

​I think this is the meaning implied: 
[ C or U ] the size of a flat surface calculated by multiplying its length by its width:
the area of a rectangle. Clearly referring to the area of the each single space of the grid.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner you don't break "chunks" into "smaller areas". It has to be *bits* or *pieces* or (even) *smaller sizes*

Comment: @Mari-Lou - I said, the meaning implied. Pieces with smaller areas would  fit into the grid.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner the discussion isn't about what the writer meant but whether "areas" in this context is correct or idiomatic. It is neither.

Comment: @FumbleFingers the reason that I work on this sample is because it was evaluated as band score 9, the othrwise I wouldnt even dwell on it that much at all. So I'm not quite sure to what extend it is right  describing it to be of poor quality as I'm not a native

Comment: @Cavid: Well, I *am* a "native", so you can take it from me the sentence *is* poor quality. But Mari-Lou's not a native speaker either, and even she knows Anglophones don't use ***areas*** in contexts like this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, ok then. Do you think the same for the entire text or is it worth working on it as a valuable source, please share your thoughts.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  I don't know, I'm quite puzzled now about If I have to look at it as a valid piece of composition.

Comment: @CavidHummatov My biggest complaint with the text is that it seems to invent material not present in the diagram. The grid and conveyor do not (I infer from other knowledge) work in the way they are described. It seems readable enough.

Comment: @Sean: I suppose the text is "readable" (whatever that means), but I can't actually *understand* exactly what process is being described. It might make sense if we changed *placed on a metal grid* to ***forced through** a metal grid*, but even then I can't really visualise how clods of (presumably, *wet*) clay would be *segregated* (separated?) by passing over a roller. It's a very curious example that's probably not helped by having a structure requiring 4 separate synonyms, each meaning a "dollop" of clay (but however you look at it, ***area*** isn't a credible synonym here).

Comment: I'd disagree that the source material is poor - "smaller areas" is perfectly valid in this context. I've used this terminology before to describe a similar process. 

Areas describe the surface of an object - when you break an object into pieces, generally you decrease the surface area. Smaller areas is perfectly valid. Whether the text accurately describes the process is a completely separate issue.

Comment: @Charleh: If you break an object into pieces, you ***always increase*** the [total] surface area. That's why granulated sugar dissolves faster than lump suger, for example.

Comment: @FumbleFingersy they increase the total surface area, but the area of each of the smaller pieces will generally be less (unless you broke them in a way that increased the surface area for the smaller bits, but that's unlikely without some thoughtful destruction), therefore "smaller areas" - hence the plural :)

Comment: @Kik volume is similar to area in that given an object with a roughly spherical volume you can deduce the area, and vice versa. Chunks of clay are probably going to be roughly spherical when broken up... just saying, I'd use "areas" - I don't have a problem with the word. I don't think the whole text accurately analogues the process, but that's a different matter. Don't forget, language is also subjective (and regionally variant)!

Comment: @Charleh: I understand perfectly well what you *meant*, but the fact of the matter is native speakers simply wouldn't use "smaller areas" to mean "smaller **pieces**" (which each have smaller surface areas than the larger piece from which they were formed).

Comment: Except I'm a native speaker and I can happily understand/use the word in that context... I'm not saying I couldn't use another word - I'm just saying I don't believe it's incorrect in this context. It's valid.

Comment: We're going round in circles. We can both *understand* it, but surely you don't seriously maintain that you would *use* this phrasing. If you do, I'd have to question your command of English.

Comment: Like I said, subjective :) - you can check out some of my other posts on the network (mostly on StackOverflow) if you'd like to question my command of the English language. I'm sure there are some questionable phrases here and there which could be clarified if recomposed, but on the whole I believe I'm doing alright.

Answer (score 3):

Unless there is more context to the quote, where `areas` has already been introduced as a specific way of referring to a specific part of the machine, this is simply the wrong word. There is no common context where `area` can be equated with the result of breaking down a `big chunk`.

Alternative words to describe this stage in the process (although the context would also need to be changed) might be:
`crumb` - This is understood to be a fragment (but probably there is a better 'specialist' term amongst clay working)
`lump`, `fragment` - other generic words describing something which is broken down
`cube`, `segement`, `bar` - describing the shape as in some way regular.

> Then the lumps of clay are placed on a metal grid in order to break up the big chunks of clay into much smaller *elongated bars*, which are *forced* through the metal grid onto a roller, whose motion further segregates the bits of clay.

You could write this, or infer this meaning from the original test

> Then the lumps of clay are placed on a vibrating metal grid. This breaks up the clay and only allows small chunks to pass through. A vibrating belt transports the clay and further breaks down the chunks to smaller parts.

This is more a accurate description of the process as I imagine it.

Comment: The link can be found in Fumblefingers' answer and in the comment section beneath the OP

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph but I wouldn't say "...break up the big chunks of clay into much smaller *lumps* OR *bars*, which fall through..."

Comment: Fair enough, I wan't thinking of a drop-in replacement word, more of the correct word to use in a replacement.

Answer (score 2):

"Area" refers to a two-dimensional shape such as a square or rectangle.

So if you look down at the top of the surface of the clay:

1. Before it passes through the grid, there will be one large area of clay;
2. After it passes through the grid, it will have been cut into lots of smaller squares or rectangles - each will have a much smaller area.

Comment: that was what I want to clarify to begin with, Is it a particular shape which is referred to as "area" and used within architectural  terminology because what has first come in my mind so far about this word is that this imply a particular  region, or field ,place etc.

Comment: This seems a contrived way of justifying what looks to me like a poor choice of word.